# Binary executable from Debian to Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gcc, cross-compilation

I compiled some big c++ programs with gcc 4.9 on Debian. I want to know if the executable binary code is compatible and safe also on ubuntu, or must recompile program on Ubuntu?

Comment: Short answer: Cross-compilation is for other arquitectures/processors, Ubuntu drinks from Debian unstable, and normally the libraries are some versions ahead, since you have the source, you would better compile it.

Comment: Try running `ldd` on the executable, and see if all the required libraries are present. However, in general there are no guarantees. To be on the safe side, recompile.

Comment: I would always recompile to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with core library that is widespread across all current Linuxes - glibc. It incorporates a "feature" called "symbol versioning" that adds an ability to have more than one version of each standard function inside the libc shared library and supporting libs that come with glibc.

For example, your resulting binary can depend on "GLIBC_2.15" symbol versions, and your target system provides a maximum of "GLIBC_2.14". Then you will get a fatal error message and nothing more.

Some glibc versions even refuse to run on older kernels or even hardware, but it's rare.

With glibc, compiling statically is not an option too (if you'd thought about that), because certain glibc parts can require dynamic libs even from static programs (during compiling and linking you will get a warning if it takes a place).

If you need to make one binary to run on many systems, you want to use another libc. If you just want one binary to run on other system, it's better to rebuild it on that system.

In certain cases (not applies to glibc), if your target is very slow, you can copy your compiled source tree, touch all object (*.o) files and remove binary. Then running `make` will just relink it.

Please note also that many (but not all!) third party libraries can also enforce symbol versioning requirements, and this applies to them too.